# Database naming convention - prefix

Tags: database-design, naming-conventions

I know there are a lot of questions targeting this issue.
Although there are many good naming convention suggestions out there, we had a debate in our team.

A team member insist that we should name our table's like that: sProducts
and the primary key like that: ProductGuid

There are two prefixe's in his system (s, h) so s stands for static and h - sorry i really don't know. I can see absolutely no logic in there. He says that every big oracle and ibm system is working like that. I've never worked with a oracle or ibm system, so is there a convention for adding prefixes like s and h? And what do they stand for?

Somebody out there, who does the same? I'm sorry for that question - but I don't want to always add an s and have no clue why...

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not really a database administrator, but I am someone who did a fair bit of database design and development (including Oracle and even a little bit of DB2), and I never used nor heard somebody using this particular naming convention. I don't even know what "static" means in this context - you should ask your colleague for more details. Also, the usual ER modelling convention is to use singular for entity names.

Comment: I guess by "static" he means data that doesn't change much over time, which is a rather arbitrary designation (almost no table is 100% "static" i.e. never ever changes).  But as for "h" - not a clue.  It must just have been the standard somewhere he worked once and he likes it.  It does no harm, it does no good I can see either.  At least it is preferable to the "tbl_" prefix that so many people seem to like...

Comment: Yes that's true, although some data in there are relatively static, they change. In my opinion I would name my table Product and the primary key just Id. I'll try to find out what the h stands for..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> He says that every big oracle and ibm system is working like that.

That's a pretty bold statement. Odds are he's wrong, and I'd say that even if I didn't know anything about databases. (I've been a consultant in more than 800 companies. I've never seen this.)

Encoding today's beliefs in a table name creates problems for tomorrow. It's not unusual for tables to become views, for views to become tables, for views to become table-valued functions, and for static tables to become, umm, the "h-word" tomorrow.

When a static table finally becomes the h-word, what do you do with the table? Leave the name alone? Now you have to think harder every time you need to find that table. Change the name to an h-word? Now you've broken all the apps that rely on it being static. Change the name and create an updatable view with the old name? Seems like a lot of work that could be avoided by a good name in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused by the presentation of your question.  You mention "suffix" yet you show "prefix."

There are many religious issues here...

I present this in context of fields/columns/attributes.  Other kinds of thingies also need to have consistent forms.

The root source of many naming conventions—not the same thing as naming standards—is IBM's "OF Language" from the 1970s.

OF used a PRIME-MODIFIER-CLASS format, producing CUST-ACCT-NO for customer account number.

A good name would hope to accomplish several tasks... indicate what kind of data it was (e.g a date or text) and what it was to the business.

The CLASS word (suffix, but a prefix in Hungarian Notation) would be a short list of what today would be something like data types.  Date, Text, Code, Flag (binary today), Amount, & so forth.

CLASS words shouldn't be more than a dozen or two.

PRIME/MODIFIER words would be more focused on business issues the system was supporting.

In any case... the hardest part is to be consistent.

BIG no no to abbreviate CODE as CD and CDE.

Separator issues such as dash (-), underscore (_), camelCase are dictated by the technical environment & not worth discussing.

Throughout any of these issues the most important issue is CONSISTENCY... something that humans are terrible at.

There is no correct naming convention.  If what you dream up is too complex for others to grok, then you've made a bad choice.

BTW... a naming convention is what we mostly deal with... a foggy idea, that with luck is written down in a dusty, forgotten manual.

Naming standards are something that is automatically enforced, just the same as your compiler.

I've worked on a large system that had excellent naming conventions (enforced by the DBA)... the sense of being able to glance at a data element or a paragraph name & know what it was was most liberating.

Comment: English is probably not his first language.